# BuddyPress Title displays incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, themes, title, buddypress

I have my own theme and Buddypress installed on my Wordpress page but when I updated to the newest version (1.7.2) the titles of the BuddyPress pages display incorrectly (Profile page, Groups page, …): They show in a HTML form. On the twenty twelve theme everything looks good.
As an alternative I tried creating a new theme for BuddyPress (using the groups, members, … folders in my theme folder) but I found it too much of work to do. Isn't there a simple solution for only the title.
A screenshot of my groups title:
[image: Title of the groups page] 
A screenshot how it is supposed to look: 
[image]

```
<div id="page">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h2 id="page_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p id="author"><?php the_author(); ?></p>
<div class="content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
</div><!-- main -->
```

Comment: I found that Wordpress changes the link in the title so the <a href="link"> tag is changed to &lt;a href="link"&gt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the "Remove private/protected from post titles" snippet from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-privateprotected-from-post-titles/) in my functions.php. After I deleted it, it worked again.